# Scaling behavior of the width of a distribution

Tags: distributions, scales, beta-distribution

I'm considering the following distribution on the interval $[-1,1]$:

$$p(x)=\frac{1}{N}(1-x)^{n-p}(1+x)^p$$

where $N$ is a normalization factor while
$n, p \in \mathbb N $ and
$2\leq n$ and $ 1\leq p\leq n-1$.

Can I evaluate how the width of the distribution scales with $n$ ?
Especially I'm interested in the length of the interval given by $$\{ x\in[-1,1]\mid p(x)< \lambda\},\space\space\space\space\space\space \lambda\in \mathbb R$$

Comment: How is $p$ supposed to vary as $n$ varies?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the change of variable$$Y=\frac{1+X}{2}$$the density of $Y$ is given by
$$f_Y(y)=N^{-1}(1-2y+1)^{n-p}(1+2y-1)^p\times 2=2^{n+1}N^{-1}(1-y)^{n-p}y^p\mathbb{I}{[0,1]}(y)\,.$$
This means that $Y$ is distributed from a Beta $\text{Be}(p+1,n-p+1)$ distribution, and that the normalisation constant is
$$N=\frac{2^{-n-1}\Gamma(n+2)}{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(n-p+1)}$$
In particular, the density peaks with $n$, being centred at $\frac{p+1}{n+2}$ and with a variance of $$\frac{p(n-p)}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}$$which decreases hence concentrates in $1/n$. Here are a few densities with a fixed ratio $p/n=.3$

[image: Beta densities]